# Does slick care if I have a foreign key setup in my database?

Tags: scala, slick

When making joins using slick, does slick care if I have a foreign key constraint setup at the database schema level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick will work regardless of if your Slick schema has a foreign key defined or not.

This is from the [Constraints](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#constraints) section of the docs:

> Independent of the actual constraint defined in the database, such a foreign key can be used to navigate to the referenced data with a join. For this purpose, it behaves the same as a manually defined utility method for finding the joined data.